Can't pip install cvzone on Raspberry
I'm trying to install cvzone on my Raspberry pi
pip install cvzone

but I always get this error `
–
/usr/local/bin/python3.10 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/__pip-runner__.py install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-4q_x96pu/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url piwheels.org/simple -- 'cmake>=3.1' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'aarch64'"'"' and platform_machine != '"'"'arm64'"'"'' 'num 








  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.

  │ exit code: 2

  ╰─> See above for output.

  

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

  [end of output]

Note:

Numpy version: 1.21.6
Python version: 3.7.3
It's likely to be a compatible issue between Numpy version and Python version.

I tried different ways to install cvzone with different versions:
pip install cvzone
pip install cvzone==x.y.z
I did all the apt update and upgrade.
With sudo also and it doesn't install on my Raspberry.

sudo apt update    sudo pip3 install cvzone

@toyotaSupra It's likely to be a compatible issue, what do you think?

I used Bookworm, RPi 4 and 5 with 8 GB

@toyotaSupra Can you tell me what version of numpy and Python you used to install cvzone? And what's the version of cvzone you installed?

I used Numpy 2. I was downloaded yesterday. And the cvzone 1.6.1
